# Convert Delphi Enumerated type to Similar thing in C#

Tags: c#, delphi

I am new at c# and have been programming for many years in Delphi. I am stuck on the following problem and I hope someone can help me.

In Delphi you could declare a type:

```
type
  TBtn = (btYes, btNo, btOK);
```

then create a procedure

```
procedure TfrmMain.Button(ABtn: TBtn);
begin
  //Do something;
end;
```

and call the procedure like this

```
Button(btYes);
```

or

```
Button(btNo);
```

I want to do the same thing in C#

```
public Button (ABtn TBtn, string AString){
//Do Someting;
}
```

and call it

```
Button(btYes,"Hallo World");
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I think you are talking about C# `enum`

Comment: Make it `TBtn aBtn`, not the other way around.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Delphi that is an [enumerated type](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Simple_Types#Enumerated_Types). The C# equivalent is an [`enum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx).

Declare the type like this:

```
enum Btn {Yes, No, OK};
```

Declare the function like this:

```
public void Button(Btn btn, string str)
{
    // Do Something;
}
```

And call the function like so:

```
Button(Btn.Yes, "Hallo World");
```

While you are still learning C#, I would recommend that you keep an introductory text close to hand.